# How to animate a graph generated by ListPlot command point by point?

Tags: plotting, animation, sequence

I was wondering if it is possible to animate the following graph.

[image]

The command used to generate the graph is the following:

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{1, 2}}, {{1, 3}}, {{1, 4}}, {{2, 1}}, {{2, 
2}}, {{3, 1}}, {{3, 2}}, {{4, 1}}, {{4, 2}}}, 
PlotMarkers -> {{"\[Pi]", Large}, {"8", Large}, {"9", Large}, {"10", 
Large}, {"2", Large}, {"5", Large}, {"3", Large}, {"4", 
Large}, {"1", Large}, {"\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\)", Large}}, 
Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
AxesLabel -> {"Number of columns", "Size of the columns"}, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 20, Arrowheads[0.03]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Large], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], 
TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 20], ImageSize -> Large]
```

Ideally, I would like to animate a graph where I arrange the numbers of the sequence $(\pi,2,8,9,5,10,3,4,1,\sqrt{2})$ using Hammersley's argument ([see J. Michael Steele, "Variations on the Monotone subsequence theme of Erdős and Szekeres"](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/PDF/VOTMSTOEAS.pdf))
.

[image]

So, first $\pi$, then $2$ in the next column, then $8$ and $9$ above $\pi$ and so on.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion or hint.

Thank you.

Comment: For completeness, can you give a reference for this?

Comment: @J.M. What do you mean?

Comment: From what book/paper/whatever did you see "Hammersley's argument"?

Comment: @J.M. Okay, thanks. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I understand your question:

```
hammersley = With[{k = If[#1 === {}, {}, Position[Last /@ #1, x_ /; x < #2]]}, 
                  If[k === {}, Append[#1, {#2}],
                     MapAt[Function[l, Append[l, #2]], #1, First[k]]]] &;

myList = {π, 2, 8, 9, 5, 10, 3, 4, 1, Sqrt[2]};

gathered = Rest[FoldList[hammersley, {}, myList]];
dims = Dimensions[PadRight[Last[gathered]]];

ListAnimate[
    Graphics[MapIndexed[Text, #, {2}],
             PlotRange -> Transpose[{{1, 1}/2, dims + 1/2}]] &
    /@ gathered]
```

[image: Hammersley's sort?]

---

With axes:

```
ListAnimate[
    Graphics[MapIndexed[Text, #, {2}], Axes -> True,
             PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, dims + 1/2}]] &
    /@ gathered]
```

[image: but really, wasn't it apparent?]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although, is it possible to include the axes? And also how did you export it as a gif?

Comment: I can do the axes, but maybe later. As for exporting, I used `Export[]` instead of `ListAnimate[]`.

Comment: J.M., I would like to know that did you have a copy of this paper :[**The insertion algorithm**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010448585902465). The lbrary of our university doesn't buy the paper that published before  1993.

Comment: @J.M. I cannot understand the **algorithm 5.4** of **Knot Refinement** in **page 165** of "*The NURBS Book*" without that paper.